# arabi.sty not found

Tags: packages, arabic

I have  the *arabi* package installed with texlive in mint.
I have added the command `\usepackage{arabi}` in the preamble of my document.
When I compiled with pdflatex I get the error message "file arabi.sty not found".
So I have looked for the above mentioned file in the folder containing the package files but I didn't find it.
how to fix this issue?

Comment: I have already used this package in miketex without any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`arabi`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/arabic/arabi) package for writing  arabic, instead of `\usepackage{arabi}` you must add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
```